# How can I bind the rowheight between two DataGrids?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, row

I have two DataGrids with the same number of rows. But it can be that a row in DataGrid1 has more text in it and the rowheight will be bigger than in DataGrid2.  I already tried something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid1.Items[i]);
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            Binding bindingHeight = new Binding();
            bindingHeight.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            bindingHeight.Source = row.ActualHeight;
            bindingHeight.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.HeightProperty);

            DataGrid2.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid2.Items[i]);
            DataGridRow row2 = (DataGridRow)DataGrid2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(row2, DataGridRow.HeightProperty, bindingHeight);
        }
```

Any ideas how I can get the rows to have the same height?

**Edit:**
The problem is that i want to bind the rowheight of a single row.
This is how it looks at the moment:
[image]
But I want that a specific row in DataGrid2 has the rowheight of the other row in DataGrid1. So e.g. that the row with the ID 12940 + rm in DataGrid2 has the same height as the row in DataGrid1.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the binding in XAML: `RowHeight="{Binding ElementName=m_DataGrid1, Path=RowHeight}"`

Or if you really want to bind in code behind:

```
 m_DataGrid2.SetBinding(DataGrid.RowHeightProperty, new Binding("RowHeight")
            {
                Source = m_DataGrid1
            });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I was looking for sth else, see my edit above